# Use base64Data to save image to camera roll with meadiaScanner:true but It saved wrong place in Ionic 4

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, base64, camera-roll

I am coding an App have a feature which save image to gallery in Ionic 4. After research I found base64ToGallery to save img to camera roll with very detail. But it didn't save to camera roll. It save to Library location. 
There is my code.

```js
let base64Data = this.convertToDataURLviaCanvas(this.listItem[0], 'image/jpeg').then(base64Data => {
      this.base64ToGallery.base64ToGallery(base64Data, { prefix: '_img', mediaScanner: true  }).then(
        res => console.log('Saved image to gallery ', res),
        err => console.log('Error saving image to gallery ', err)
      );
    }
```

I expect the output show /Media/.... or something to tell me image saved in camera roll. But the actual output is:

```
2019-05-13 16:17:18.269107+0700 MyApp[3383:933160] Saved image to gallery  /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8214F568-87C5-494C-8CDE-C17C55BBEB83/Library/NoCloud/_img122206160949.png
```

Base64ToGallery in ionic 4 said:

```
Base64ToGalleryOptions
mediaScanner    boolean 
On Android runs Media Scanner after file creation. On iOS if true the file will be added to camera roll, otherwise will be saved to a library folder.
```

I'm really appreciates if anyone can help me fix this. I'm using ionic 4, angular 7, ios 12.2.

Comment: "This plugin allows you to save base64 data as a png image into the device",  i think this means saving into device(saving in some file path).

Comment: @SaEChowdary Hm... so the solution is modify the path to camera roll folder. Thanks for make me realize that, I will figure out with this opinion. But hope still another way.

Comment: @NetNoft did you figure out a way to save it to the camera roll ?